# Initializing javascript objects with variables that are functions within a for loop -- how to avoid overwriting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        $("body").append(questions[i]);

        for(j = 0; j < prompts.length; j++){
            var temp_id = "slider-" + j;
            var temp_num_text_id = "slider-text-" + j;

            var temptextdiv = $("<h5>50</h5>");
            $("body").append(temptextdiv);
            temptextdiv.attr('id', temp_num_text_id);

            var tempdiv = $("<div></div>");
            $("body").append(tempdiv);
            tempdiv.attr('id', temp_id);

            $("#" + temp_id).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 50,
                slide: function(event, ui){
                    $("#" + temp_num_text_id).html(ui.value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The goal is to have one question with various prompts about the question, each being a ranking done on a jquery-ui slider. My trouble is trying to 'link' the text that displays the value of the slider with the slider itself. When I was testing this out with one slider it was as simple as the function within the declaration of the slider object shown above, but when this is done within a loop, all of the sliders only change the text value of the last slider. As I understand it from similar questions others have had, every iteration of the loop overwrites the previous declaration. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your `questions` and `prompts` data.

Comment: Also, this `for` loop would only run once for `i < 1` only happens when `i = 0`.

Comment: Your prompts will create repeated `id` attributes and this will create problems: `slider-0`, `slider-1`, slider-2`. So this will cause slider to be reassigned in each loop for all the same selectors.

Comment: @Twisty prompts and questions are simply arrays of strings. My problem is that all of the sliders end up changing only one of the appended divs (namely the last one -- as in moving any slider only changes the value of one 'id' as it were). It seems like the function that is the slider variable is run for all of the iterations before the rest of the loop is, so they all end up changing the last one. I'm having trouble linking the ids to the text they represent.

Comment: Posted a answer with working example.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, all `id` attributes should be unique. This can be done by assigning a consecutive number to the ids.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vLut8ysw/

**JavaScript**

```
var questions = [
  "<div id='q1'>Question 1</div>",
  "<div id='q2'>Question 2</div>",
  "<div id='q3'>Question 3</div>",
  "<div id='q4'>Question 4</div>",
  "<div id='q5'>Question 5</div>",
];

var prompts = [
  25,
  50,
  75,
];

var promptIds = 0;

$(function() {
  $.each(questions, function(q, i) {
    $(i).appendTo("body");
    $.each(prompts, function(p, j) {
      var temptextdiv = $("<h5>", {
        id: "p-slider-text-" + promptIds
      }).html(j).appendTo("body");

      var tempdiv = $("<div></div>", {
        id: "p-slider-" + promptIds
      }).appendTo("body");

      tempdiv.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: j,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          temptextdiv.html(ui.value);
        }
      });

      promptIds++;
    });
  });
});
```

This will create unique ids for each slider.